# Stop / start a function replying itself

Tags: javascript, jquery, settimeout

I have this code:

```
function functionName(){
    // blablabla
    // dosomething
    setTimeout(functionName, 5000);
}
```

Well i want to make it if a user presses a button that the function stops replying itself...
So that the code becomes

```
function functionName(){
    // blablabla
    // dosomething

}
```

and when he presses a button again that it starts again...

```
function functionName(){
    // blablabla
    // dosomething
    setTimeout(functionName, 5000);
}
```

How can i do that (with jquery) ?

Greetings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its pretty simple you can use toggle() from JQuery and pass it two methods. One that starts the function and the other that stops the timeout.

```
var timeoutId;

function functionName(){
    // blablabla
    // dosomething

    timeoutId = setTimeout(functionName, 2000);
}


$(document).ready(function(){   
    $('#myButton').toggle( function() {
        functionName();
    }, function() {
        clearTimeout(timeoutId);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

`setTimeout` returns an access-id. That id can be used to call `clearTimeout()` which stops the current timeout and therefore ends your "functional-loop";

```
function functionName() {
    if( this.tID ) {
        clearInterval(tID);
        delete this.tID;
    }

    // do something

    this.tID = setTimeout(functionName, 5000);
}
```

`this` would refer the `window` object called just like that. Probably a better idea to use your own namespace to store the id.

Answer (score 0):

To stop the timer you can use `clearTimeout`.

```
var timerId = setTimeout(functionName, 5000);

clearTimeout(timerId);
```

As for the logic to run a function you can just check to see which button was clicked.

I wasn't 100% clear on what you were looking for so this will at least answer your question as to how to stop a timer.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to set up a toggling function to alternate the setTimeout action from on to off:

```
(function toggler() { // don't pollute the global scope

  var temp;
  var running = false;
  var myfunc = function() {
    do_your_stuff_here(); // a pulsing red box in the Fiddle example
    running = true;
    temp = setTimeout(myfunc, 1000);
  }

  $('#toggle').click(function(e) { // toggler control is a link
    e.preventDefault();
    if (running) {
      clearTimeout(temp); // turn it off
      running = false;
    } else {
      myfunc(); // or turn it on
    }
  });

  myfunc(); // kickstart it

})();
```

Here's a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/redler/XKTW9/